# Confused about the choice between Python 2 vs Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I am coming from Ruby, and am having trouble deciding between installing and using Python 2.x or Python 3.x I am guessing that this choice this depends on what platforms and frameworks I want to use, but how can I find a list of programs that are or are not Python 3 compatible? This might help me get past this dilemma.

Comment: What kind of application are you looking to develop?

Comment: Sorry, I meant Python 2.x vs Python 3.x

Comment: Also, is there any reason to limit yourself to just one?  I find python versions/distributions to be a lot like pieces of cheesecake.  Once you have one, you just want to get your hands on some more ...

Comment: Just call it Python 2 vs Python 3; easier.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I learn Python 2 before 3, or start directly from Python 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170921/should-i-learn-python-2-before-3-or-start-directly-from-python-3)

Comment: This answer hasn't changed for years: Use Python 3 if all the libraries you need support it. Otherwise use Python 2. The differences aren't big, it's not hard for a programmer to switch from one to another (although it can be hard for software to do so).

Answer (score 9):

If you're looking to learn new things, and aren't looking to make a "must work today" type project, try Python3. It will be easier to move forward into the future with Python3, as it will become the standard over time.

If you're making something quick and dirty, you'll typically get better library support with Python 2.7.

Finally, if anything you are using includes full unicode support, don't sell yourself short -- go with Python3. The simplification of unicode alone is worth it.

Answer (score 2):

PyPI let's you select packages by the [Python 3 classifier](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=browse&c=533&show=all).

That's a big list though, and not necessarily very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The Python Package Index (PyPI) lists the [packages compatible with Python 3](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=browse&c=533&show=all).

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, quite a number of libraries support Python 3. There is not a single list of these, so you'll have to check the frameworks you'd like to use for Python 3 compatibility. Some support Python 3 only in some beta stage, but that doesn't mean those are bad.

I would start off nowadays with Python 3, and see where you get. Only if you know you need to support whatever you are developing on other platforms that you don't control, it may be better to start with Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

At this point, I would start telling people to use 3.x if the specific library that you need is available in 3.x. If you are developing on windows, here is an excellent list of [binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Answer (score 1):

http://python3wos.appspot.com/

Here's a cool site about what packages are compatible with python 3.